# Nautilus can not display FTP files, FileZilla and comman-line 'ftp' can

Tags: nautilus, ftp

Does anyone know why Nautilus would allow me to login to a server but not display any files, but when I log in via the 'ftp' command-line binary, it works and allows me to display all the files, make directories, etc.?

I was able to login and see/edit files via FileZilla too. Here's part of the log:

```
Code:
Response: 220 Microsoft FTP Service
Command: USER ----
Response: 331 Password required for ----.
Command: PASS ***********
Response: 230-Welcome to the Alentus FTP server.
Response: 230 User ---- logged in.
Command: SYST
Response: 215 Windows_NT
Command: FEAT
Response: 211-FEAT
Response:     SIZE
Response:     MDTM
Response: 211 END
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
```

Something to do with gio/gvfs?

- Ubuntu 10.10
- Nautilus 2.32.0
- FileZilla 3.3.3
- ftp 0.17-23

Comment: Can you give us an example (public) FTP server to see whether we get the same issue?

Comment: It's for a client so I doubt they have a public ftp user. I'm just wondering if it has to do with 'PASSIVE' mode or something of the like and if it can be changed in Nautilus through the ftp://user@domain URI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a gvfs issue, where it cannot connect to some FTP servers. See the relevant bug report at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=516704
If you can identify a public FTP server that uses the same FTP server software, it might be possible to identify what aspect of the FTP protocol is at fault, and ask for a fix.
Therefore, for now, you can use an alternative FTP client.